# Jupyter file path change to project location

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have experience in RStudio and Visual Studio and new to Python environment, I am struggling to set Python project in Jupyter like above two IDE. Here when I open new notebook then it create it as default location and I am not finding a way to put the file in my project location, Just want to know how to make production ready project like folder structure in Jupyter.

If this post is duplicate then I am not able to search the original one.

Comment: I found this link as useful, watch the video specially after 16 minutes 
https://svds.com/jupyter-notebook-best-practices-for-data-science/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Linux, specify which directory Jupyter notebook uses to locate the notebooks with the command:

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=<path to notebook location>
```

I have this aliased in my .bashrc file to jupytern.

In Windows I created a desktop shortcut and specified the notebook directory as:

```
C:\python36\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe --notebook-dir=<path to notebook locations>
```

You need to change the path to the jupyter-notebook.exe file to where it is on your installation.